# Get object from container that was injected in dependency?

Tags: c#, moq

it is possible in Moq Framework this?

I properly configure the container and use it but it is possible to get an concrete instance of type that was injected? For example a injected an repository to my service and I would like to get the repository instance used in service, it is possible?

```
_container.Configure(c =>
{
c.For<IUserApplicationService>().Use<UserApplicationService>();
c.For<IRepository<LegalEntity>>().Use<LegalEntityRepository>();
c.For<IRepository<User>>().Use<UserRepository>();
c.For<ILocalMembershipService>().Use<AspMembershipServiceAdapter>();
c.For<IEmailService>().Use(emailStub);
});
```

now I do it that way that i use single single object for `IEmailService` dependency

and what i want is to get on the fly object created. it isnt possible probably

Comment: Could you please add a code snippet of how you are injecting, etc?  Would help.

Comment: Are you saying you used Moq to implement an interface, configured a DI container with this, and resolved an instance of another type that depended on the mocked interface with the DI container? If that's the case then effectively there is no concrete type - it's a type Moq generated on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to acces your base type from your injected interface? You can always cast, but that would be against the DI principles.

Comment: How is up casting to a base type against DI principles? It's just using LSP.

Comment: Because you are not supposed to have to be aware that the base class even exists.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your container supports factories, how about setting up a factory for IEmailService in the container that creates a mock of IEmailService, stores it somewhere accessible to your tests and returns the mock.